# Recommended Ubuntu phone application development tutorials

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, qt, phone, qml

Where can I find good QML tutorials for Ubuntu phone app development?

I've seen the developer.ubuntu.com site, but that's not enough for me.

Also, which of the 2 languages can be used to develop Ubuntu phone apps: Qt or QML?

Answer (score 0):

[QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlapplications.html) is "Qt Modeling Language", it's a quick and easy way of developing Qt applications using a simple markup and JavaScript rather than C++.

The Developer Portal has the most resources, including a tutorial on QML: https://phone.docs.ubuntu.com/en/apps/qml/tutorials-building-your-first-qml-app